# How to disable automatic updates in Office 2010 Starter

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

Came across a Windows 7 setup with Office Starter 2010 installed. Every time the system boots, after a few minutes we get this annoying popup:

"An update for Microsoft Office Starter 2010 - English is now available online"
and a prompt to install it. Clicking cancel doesn't help, it keeps coming back next time.

Changing Windows Update settings didn't help, nor changing File -> options -> Trust settings inside word as found elsewhere.

How to permanently disable automatic updates for office so it never even checks for updates ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found it. Inside word click:

- `File -> Help`
- Then under `Click-to-run product updates`
- `Update Options -> Disable updates`

Now, why on earth did they put it under `File -> Help` and nowhere under `File -> Options`, don't ask me. Welcome to the new ribbon UI, we've made it "easier" to work with !

Comment: please can you specify the registry location and setting ?